# getting a color name in an R color palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to get the name or code for the colours in **Set3** colour palette of ggplot2?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `brewer.pal` from `RColorBrewer` like this:

```r
library(RColorBrewer)
brewer.pal(12, "Set3")
#>  [1] "#8DD3C7" "#FFFFB3" "#BEBADA" "#FB8072" "#80B1D3" "#FDB462" "#B3DE69"
#>  [8] "#FCCDE5" "#D9D9D9" "#BC80BD" "#CCEBC5" "#FFED6F"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

To get the names of the colors codes, you could use the function `color.id` from `plotrix` like this:

```r
library(RColorBrewer)
colors <- brewer.pal(12, "Set3")

library(plotrix)
sapply(colors, color.id)
#> $`#8DD3C7`
#> [1] "paleturquoise3"
#> 
#> $`#FFFFB3`
#> [1] "wheat1"
#> 
#> $`#BEBADA`
#> [1] "lightsteelblue"
#> 
#> $`#FB8072`
#> [1] "salmon"
#> 
#> $`#80B1D3`
#> [1] "lightskyblue3"
#> 
#> $`#FDB462`
#> [1] "sandybrown"
#> 
#> $`#B3DE69`
#> [1] "darkolivegreen2"
#> 
#> $`#FCCDE5`
#> [1] "thistle2"
#> 
#> $`#D9D9D9`
#> [1] "gray85" "grey85"
#> 
#> $`#BC80BD`
#> [1] "orchid3"
#> 
#> $`#CCEBC5`
#> [1] "darkseagreen1"
#> 
#> $`#FFED6F`
#> [1] "lightgoldenrod1"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! These palettes come from ‘RColorBrewer’ and, using that package, you can get the color values from each palette via the following code:

```
palette = 'Set3'
brewer.pal(brewer.pal.info[palette, 'maxcolors'], palette)
```